# Populating more than 1 property in a subdocument using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

For argument's sake, say I have a the following mongoose models

```
REGION: {  
_id  
name  
teams (TEAM)  
}

TEAM {  
_id  
name  
region (REGION)  
coach (COACH)  
players (PLAYER)  
}

COACH {  
_id  
name  
team (TEAM)   
}

PLAYER{  
_id  
name  
team (TEAM)  
}
```

And I wanted to populate a region object with all their teams and finally the teams with their coach and players, how would I go about that

Answer (score 0):

I would flip it : think in terms of Player docs. each has a coach, team, region.  So load the Player docs with those fields....   then you'll be able to set up index on those fields and efficiently query them....

Comment: Thanks for the comment.This approach however will fetch several instances of the same team object, depending on the number of players, (the N + 1 problem) which is not scalable. Also supposing there are no players in that team, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: that's the process - NoSQL - is not normalized, so working backwards from the query needs helps a lot...so putting the team/region info onto the player doc is better than thinking relational... you still need either a team collection or maybe a dummy player doc as a placeholder so a team exists... but you can index on team and then do a group/distinct when query so you don't result in a final of multiple.... the key is to avoid linked docs and be able to query on index - - that's the fastest....